# Can no longer login to Graph Explorer

Tags: authentication, graph, explorer

I've been using Graph Explorer for a good while, but not just recently (couple of months or so); I came back to it and found I could no longer login; by that I mean I try to login, it *seems* successful, but leaves me *not logged in*. Further investigation revealed that some of the logins I can use work, but most of them - the ones I used to use - no longer do. Finally, what's the meaning of the Login in the top right corner, if logged in there, it still treats all web calls as sample account. Help!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a browser problem: I was using Edge (recommended by MS for W10), but this regressed a while ago, effectively preventing login. I found that Epic works fine.